# Using DiscUtils Library to open VDI image

Tags: c#

I want to open .vdi or.vdh files with DiscUtils library and view their contents. I tried several times but failed. Can you help me with this?

```
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"D:\kali\KALI_LINUX_2022_1\KALI_LINUX_2022_1.vdi", FileMode.Open))
            {
                CDReader cd = new CDReader(fs, true, true);
                foreach (var dir in cd.Root.GetDirectories())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
                }
            }
```

```
            using (FileStream VDIStream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\123.vdi"))
            {

                using DiscUtils.Vdi.DiskImageFile baseFile = new DiscUtils.Vdi.DiskImageFile(VDIStream);
                var disk = new DiscUtils.Vdi.Disk(new List<DiscUtils.Vdi.DiskImageFile> { baseFile }, Ownership.Dispose);
                var manager = new VolumeManager(disk);
                var logicalVolumes = manager.GetLogicalVolumes();
                foreach (var volume in logicalVolumes)
                {
                    var fsInfos = FileSystemManager.DetectFileSystems(volume);
                    foreach (var fsInfo in fsInfos)
                    {
                        using var fs = fsInfo.Open(volume);
                        foreach (var file in fs.GetFiles(fs.Root.FullName, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(@"D:\");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

That's how I arranged it.

(yeni List<DiscUtils.Vdi.DiskImageFile> { baseFile }, Ownership.Dispose) 'system.collections.generic.list<DiscUtils.Vdi.DiskImageFile>' cannot be converted to string I get an error.

Comment: you can help a lot with some error messages

Comment: DiscUtils.InvalidFileSystemException: 'Volume is not ISO-9660' I get an error.
But

                 CDReader cd = new CDReader(fs, true, true);
                 foreach (var dir in cd.Root.GetDirectories())
                 {
                     Console.WriteLine(dir.Name);
                 }
I don't know if this part is correct. What exactly do I need to write to be able to view the content and import a listbox

Comment: could you help me?

Comment: @waldezgeorge If I understand correctly, you are trying to read a virtual machine as if it is a CD? I am confused.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is I want to search for a file inside a virtual machine. First of all, I want to view the files inside the virtual machine.

Comment: I mean the error message is already telling you: you are opening a .VDI file and not an ISO container. 
did you try rather ```DiscUtils.Vdi.DiskImageFile(isoStream)```

Comment: I'm confused.. can you make an example for me if you have time please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to open a Virtalbox .VDI file you can iterate through the content once you have `fsInfos`!

be sure to activate the filesystem helper according to https://github.com/DiscUtils/DiscUtils/wiki/DiscUtils.FileSystems

`DiscUtils.FileSystems.SetupHelper.SetupFileSystems();`

the rest should work easily, I tested it with this FreeDOS.VDI which contains FAT filesystem and many 1000 files

```
var disk = new DiscUtils.Vdi.Disk(@"D:\FreeDOS.vdi",FileAccess.Read);

DiscUtils.FileSystems.SetupHelper.SetupFileSystems();
var manager = new VolumeManager(disk);
var logicalVolumes = manager.GetLogicalVolumes();
foreach (var volume in logicalVolumes)
{
    var fsInfos = FileSystemManager.DetectFileSystems(volume);

    foreach (var fsInfo in fsInfos)
    {
        using var fs = fsInfo.Open(volume);
        foreach (var file in fs.GetFiles(fs.Root.FullName, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

(...)
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\CACHE\PHSCACHE.H
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\CACHE\PHSCACHE.C
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\CACHE\MAKEFILE
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\CACHE\LOGCACHE.H
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\CACHE\LOGCACHE.C
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\CACHE\EMS.H
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\CACHE\EMS.ASM
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\CACHE\BLKCACHE.H
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\CACHE\BLKCACHE.C
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\APMLIB\SOURCE\TEST.C
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\APMLIB\SOURCE\APMLIBP.PAS
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\APMLIB\SOURCE\APMLIB.ERR
\FDOS\SOURCE\DEFRAG\ENGINE\APMLIB\SOURCE\APMLIB.C
(....)

Comment: using DiscUtils.Vhdx.DiskImageFile baseFile = new DiscUtils.Vhdx.DiskImageFile(VDIStream);

'Invalid VHDX file - file signature mismatch'

I get an error

Comment: virtual machine with a .vdi file of 6-7Gb also ran smoothly. However, in a virtual machine in which I installed windows (.vdi file is about 11GB in size)
                     foreach (var file in fs.GetFiles(fs.Root.FullName, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
on the line
I got System.IO.IOException: 'Corrupt record' error.

Comment: string[] array2 = fs.GetFiles(fs.Root.Name, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                    foreach (string name in array2)
i fixed it worked

Comment: https://ibb.co/Z2WfQDk While there is no problem when I read windows virtual machine(.vdi). Why do I get the error in the picture when reading Kali Linux (.vdi).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74964385/problem-copying-contents-of-virtual-machine-with-disutils Can you help with this