# Problem copying contents of virtual machine with DiscUtils

Tags: c#

I'm able to view a virtual machine image (vhdx) using the Discutils library (https://github.com/DiscUtils/DiscUtils)
There are files belonging to the Linux operating system in these Vhdx

How can I transfer these files to the windows environment because of the special characters in their names?

What came to my mind was to remove the special characters in the filenames. However, since the method I use wants to open the file first, windows does not allow it.

```
var sourceStream = fs.OpenFile(name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var targetStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"D:\" + name);
sourceStream.CopyTo(targetStream);
```

Comment: `System.IO.File.Copy()` may allow the file to be copied as long as you change the destination to not have reserved characters.  Maybe.  Try it.

Comment: Yes, I tried, it doesn't work either. Because I am not copying from a mounted disk. I open and list the contents with code via DiscUtils.

Comment: @Falco Alexander can you help me please

Comment: Post the exception message you get.

Comment: System.IO.IOException: 'Unable to find extent for block 0'

Comment: I do not fully understand the Q.
what special characters do you mean? please provide more info, examples and error messages and edit the Q.
you created a lot issues and got much info in the github repo of DiscUtils as well, can you summarize what you did, what helped?